# bison error in parsing with the grammar

Tags: bison

I am a little confused with this... My grammar for bison looks like this..

```
%%
program:
    | program func_defn
    ;

datatype: INTEGER          { $$ = currentType = Type::IntegerTy; }
    | FLOAT                { $$ = currentType = Type::FloatTy; }
    | VOID                 { $$ = currentType = Type::VoidTy; }
    | STRING_LITERAL       { $$ = currentType = Type::StringTy; }
    ;

retlist : datatype
    {
        builder->pushDataType(&getType($1));
    }
    ;

arglist: datatype IDENTIFIER 
    {
        builder->pushDataType(&getType($1));
        Symbol *sym = builder->addSymbol($2, getType($1));
        builder->pushArgName(sym);
    }
    | arglist ',' datatype IDENTIFIER 
    {
        builder->pushDataType(&getType($3));
        Symbol *sym = builder->addSymbol($4, getType($3));
        builder->pushArgName(sym);
    }
    |
    ;
//as and when we find the identifiers , we need to add them to a list and use them while constructing the prototype/func

func_defn: FUNCTION IDENTIFIER LSQUARE retlist RSQUARE '(' arglist ')' '{' 
    {
        const std::string& string = $5;
        FunctionProtoType* fp = builder->getProtoType(string);//use current dataTypeList

        /*
        if(fp == NULL) //find the prototype in the module. if not found, add a new one
            builder->addProtoType(string, getType($1), &fp);
        */

        IcErr err = builder->addFunction(*fp);
        if(err != eNoErr)
            yyerror(errMsg[err]);
    }
    ;

%%
```

I am trying to parse this line...

```
function first_method [int] (int a, int b) {
```

However, this somehow doesn't seem to parse at all. I don't have any shift-reduce or reduce-reduce conflicts.

```
Compiling file: ica_test\func_defn.icaStarting parse
Entering state 0
Reducing stack by rule 1 (line 80):
-> $$ = nterm program (1.1: )
Stack now 0
Entering state 1
Reading a token: Next token is token FUNCTION (1.1: )
Shifting token FUNCTION (1.1: )
Entering state 3
Reading a token:  Next token is token IDENTIFIER (1.1: )
Shifting token IDENTIFIER (1.1: )
Entering state 5
Reading a token: _Next token is token IDENTIFIER (1.1: )

function first_method [int] (int a, int b) {
          ^
Error on Line 1, Column 9: syntax error, unexpected IDENTIFIER, expecting LSQUAR
EError: popping token IDENTIFIER (1.1: )
Stack now 0 1 3
Error: popping token FUNCTION (1.1: )
Stack now 0 1
Error: popping nterm program (1.1: )
Stack now 0
Cleanup: discarding lookahead token IDENTIFIER (1.1: )
Stack now 0

Stopping compilation as we found some syntax errors in ica_test\func_defn.ica
!Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Is something wrong with your `IDENTIFIER` definition? - it looks like two identifiers are recognized after `function`.

Comment: Just one definition present actually.. %token<string> IDENTIFIER

Comment: And how is IDENTIFIER defined in your lex file?

Comment: As @500-InternalServerError identified, your problem seems to be that your lexical analyzer is producing two 'identifiers' in a row for 'FUNCTION first_method', which is puzzling.  Does it split on the underscore?  At the least, you need to track what `yylex()` returns to your parser, to find out why you're getting the double identifier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would guess your lexer rule for `IDENTIFIER` can't contain `_` (underscore) characters, so `first_method` is tokenized as the identifier `first`, and then the `_` doesn't match any rule, so gets echoed to stdout (the stray underscore before the `Next` in your output).  It then gets another identifier (`method`), which causes a syntax error because it is expecting a `[`.

I say "guess", becuase you don't show your lexer code, but it seems pretty likely.

You should fix this by fixing your `IDENTIFIER` rule, but you should ALSO add a final lexer rule like:

```
.        { return *yytext; }
```

to match any single character and return it to the parser rather than echoing it to the output.  That way you won't get random characters echoed to the output and ignored, and you'll get more sensible syntax errors for them -- and they'll show up in the YYDEBUG text output as tokens, so you'll know what is going on.